# Jenkins git pull fail even with correct ssh keys setup

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, bitbucket

i am still getting authentication error for my SSH git via Jenkins. I have done:

1. login to server as root, grant /var/www/project folder access to User: Jenkins
2. changed user to Jenkins
3. generate RSA keypair
4. loaded ssh agent and used ssh-add the private key
5. added public key info to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
6. set ~/.ssh to 700 and authorized_keys to 644
7. added public key to bitbucket ssh keys
8. added credentials at Jenkins portal to create SSH username with private key
9. entered private key directly into above credentials
10. setup source code management to point to ssh git and selected the ssh credentials above (no errors here)
11. Start the build but getting below errors.

    > Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample-project
    >   git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
    >   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
    >   git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:user/sample-project.git # timeout=10
    >   Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:user/sample-project.git
    >   git --version # timeout=10
    >   using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
    >   git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:user/sample-project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    >   git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
    >   git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
    >   Checking out Revision 602b327b289f58dccccff7d6b608cb71ae461cce (refs/remotes/origin/master)
    >   git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
    >   git checkout -f 602b327b289f58dccccff7d6b608cb71ae461cce
    >   Commit message: "Jenkins test"
    >   git rev-list --no-walk 602b327b289f58dccccff7d6b608cb71ae461cce # timeout=10
    >   [WeEat-Hybrid] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins1258078229157091527.sh
    >
    > - cd /var/www/sample/sample-project
    > - git pull
    >     git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
    >     fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    >
    > Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    >   and the repository exists.
    >   Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
    >   Finished: FAILURE

Comment: try to bypass Jenkins by trying to pull from the shell of the slave node as user jenkins : ie. jenkins@slave $ git pull ...

Comment: Hi, did you follow the steps exactly listed here - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html#SetupanSSHkey-ssh2 ? Step 5 is unnecessary. What do you see when you run `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` from terminal ? Did you set a passphrase for your private key ? If yes, then jenkins doesn't support a passphrase for private key. Re-setup with an empty passphrase and try again.

Comment: Hi, @ben5565 when i run  ssh -T git@bitbucket.org i got: logged in as user.
You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.

I regen a key with no passphrase, doesnt work too